# How to Group Programming cross Internet

Tags: java, networking, netbeans, vps, frame-rate

Alright, me and a few others are looking to work on a project together, and we have our own VPS to host the server as it runs, but the problem is that we need to be able to access the source at the same time to edit things; now I'm wondering if there's some sort of way to set it up via FTP or something, and if so, what if we were to unknowingly access and save the same file, it would cause loss of data.

***How can a few people and I access a source project hosted on a server at once without loss of data?*** To clarify, we're using Netbeans as our IDE, and it is a Java project, JDK 8, contains anything from text files, to image files, to java source files, so it can't restrict file types.

Comment: Use git (or any other version control system).

Comment: Try https://bitbucket.org for code repository purposes

Comment: You need a source code management system...check the free ones of github.com , bitbucket as already suggested...bitbucket gives a private repo which github does not provide unless you pay for it

Comment: If you're working with Java across multiples IDEs, I'd recommend using Maven as you build/dependency manager and Git as your source control.  Maven can generalise the project structure for different IDEs and remove the issues of "private project properties" which exist if you tried using the inbuilt build process managed by most of the IDEs

Answer (score 2):

The universal way to work on a codebase as a group is through a version control system. Version control systems allow for the merging of code to prevent data loss and give you full line-by-line history of your project. **[Git](https://git-scm.com/)** is probably the defacto at this point in time, and loads of sites will let you host Git repositories for free.

**[GitHub](https://github.com)** is one of the most widely used Git repository hosts. They offer free hosting for open-source ("public") repositories.

**[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)** is another monster, and they offer free hosting for both open and closed source repositories.

You can find many others with a simple web search. **[GitLab](https://gitlab.com/)** supposedly allows you to setup a simple local repository which may be what you're looking for.

You can refer to the [Using Git Support in NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html) article to get started.